# jscolor Color Picker is offset

Tags: javascript, html, css, jscolor

I am currently using jscolor, but when I display the picker in my webpage the rainbow part of it is offset within the rest of the picker. Here is a link to what the color picker looks like on my site: (https://ibb.co/9N8dHXs).

There is a large canvas on my site I am using for three.js graphics, and I think that might have something to do with the problem but I'm not sure, and even when I try to take the canvas away I still have the problem.

I have tried putting the color picker in all parts of html, in different containers, but no matter what I am still getting this offset.

A snippet of my html:

```html
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div class="sidebar" id="sidebar">
            <div class="controls" id="controls">
                <div>
                    <h4 class="sect-head">BACKGROUND</h4>
                    <div class="sect-child">
                        Sky Color
                        <input class="jscolor" onchange="setRendererColor(this.jscolor)" value="FFE4A6">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
     </div>
</body>
```

My jscolor css:

```css
.jscolor {
    width: 60px; 
    height: 13px;
    border: white;
    font-family: "umma";
    font-size: 10px;
}
```

Everything else works as expected, but how do I fix this graphics problem?

Comment: Could you share the site itself? There's lots of things that could be modifying that element, from CSS to some specific js.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the width of jscolor class to 100 percent and set the width of sect-child to 60 pixels

```
.jscolor {
    width: 100%; 
    height: 13px;
    border: white;
    font-family: "umma";
    font-size: 10px;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't change the color picker (where the rainbow selector part is), it instead causes the button (the part in the picture that's light green and says '8BFF70') to take up 100% the width of the page. Is there anyway I can manipulate the color picker instead?

Comment: Can you create a codepen for jsfiddle for this?, So I can help you better!

Answer (score 0):

```js
function setRendererColor(jscolor)
{
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = '#' + jscolor.value;
}
```

```css
.jscolor {
    width: 100px; 
    height: 13px;
    border: white;
    font-family: "umma";
    font-size: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jscolor/2.0.4/jscolor.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div class="sidebar" id="sidebar">
            <div class="controls" id="controls">
                <div>
                    <h4 class="sect-head">BACKGROUND</h4>
                    <div class="sect-child">
                        Sky Color
                        <input class="jscolor" onchange="setRendererColor(this)" value="FFE4A6">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
     </div>
</body>
```